# How to write the sql query when deleting selected row of a jtable?

Tags: java, sql, jtable

I have a jtable on my GUI. (tableRealProperty). I need to add, delete and update the data inside the table. and this data are from a database where it has a primary key called ClientID. the columns inside the jtable are  "Location" and "Area". 
 If i select a certain row from the jtable, it should be deleted as well as from the database, of course. My problem is that, when i click my delete button, not only the selected row is deleted but also all the data inside the table of that certain client..

here's my code for delete:

```
  private void cmdDelRPropActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
String sql = "delete FROM tblrealProperty where tblrealproperty.ClientID = ?";

    try {
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1,  txtClientID.getText());
    ((DefaultTableModel)tableRealProperty.getModel()).removeRow(tableRealProperty.getSelectedRow());
    pst.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deleted");


   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
     }

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why your table name is `tblrealProperty` and the table name in where clause is `tblRealProperty` (uppercase R)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i select a certain row from the jtable, it should be deleted as
>   well as from the database, of course. My problem is that, when i click
>   my delete button, not only the selected row is deleted but also all
>   the data inside the table of that certain client..

This sounds like you have a foreign key to tblrealproperty set on the client table with cascade delete. That means, if a client is deleted from tblrealproperty, all corresponding data with a foreign key pointed to the deleted row in tblrealproperty are deleted as well. It is a feture inside DB to prevent inconstistencies.

Comment: i set it to ON DELETE: restrict but all rows from the table are deleted.

Comment: Are we talking about one table or more than one table? When you delete the row, you mean it will delete more than that row in that one table or in more tables somewhere else?

Comment: only one table. thanks for the idea about the foreign key thing.. it helped... THANK YOU :)

Comment: But i still can't delete the selected row

Comment: Like mohit said, you must have a unique identifier for each row. If there can be one CustomerID multiple times, then you need either to add a row id or add another column to the WHERE clause (for example, Location).

Answer (score 1):

This query will definitely delete all the rows with particular ClientID.  You have to add another column to table in database say "index" which will be unique for each row in the table. then delete the row with this index:

```
 `delete FROM tblrealProperty where tblrealproperty.index = ?`
```

Comment: i did the code you give me, but it the selected row is only deleted on the GUI but not on the database. when i refresh the gui, the supposed to be deleted row is still there

Answer (score 0):

For me works perfectly, don't forget to check if `txtClientID` is an `index` with `autoincrement` in your database. If your table have similar `txtClientID`, your delete command execute delete of all rows with the same `txtClientID`.